# ¿Cómo obtener valores de registros desde la base de datos de firebase?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, firebase, firebase-messaging

Desarrollo una aplicación web y necesitó  usar notificaciones push, dentro de la aplicación y estoy usando Firebase para ello… ya puedo usar varias de funcionalidades.

Ahora necesitó recuperar registros desde la db.

Así envió el payload del mensaje

```
function SendNotify() {
    const txt = document.getElementById('msj');
    var notificationMessage = txt.value;

    if (!notificationMessage) return false;

    database.ref('/notifications')
        .push({
            user: auth.currentUser.displayName,
            message: notificationMessage,
            userProfileImg: auth.currentUser.photoURL,
            date: date
        })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById('msj').value = '';
        })
        .catch(() => {
            console.log("error enviando");
        });

    txt.value = '';   
}
```

y en la DB de FireBase se ve asi :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy intentando tratar de tomar datos desde aqui y concatenarlos a otro mensaje

escribi esto  y sirve pero los campo de la DB llegan como undefined:

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.Notifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onWrite(async (change, context) => {
        const user = context.params.user;
        const message = context.params.message;
        const userProfileImg = context.params.userProfileImg;
        const date = context.params.date;

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `Test SocialWifi de: ${user}`,
                body: `Hoy: ${date} , Nuevo Mensaje  ${message}`,
                icons: `${userProfileImg}`,
                click_action: 'https://sudokudetodos.com'
            }
        };

        console.info(payload);

    });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberias cambiar tu trigger de la funcion a `onCreate` ya que estas esperando a que una notificacion sea creada, si usas `onWrite()` cada vez que se escriba el documento tu funcion va a saltar, por lo que se va a enviar varias veces la notificacion.

Si vas a usar async en la funcion, deberias usar await en la obtencion de cada valor del objeto que se esta creando antes de enviar la notificacion, entonces te aseguras que cada valor es capturado antes de hacer el build del payload.

Para obtener los datos, **snap** nos devuelve el objeto entero con los valores, usamos `snap.data()` para obtener el valor seguido del nombre del atributo que queremos obtener

```
exports.Notifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
    .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
        const user = await snap.data().user;
        const message = await snap.data().message;
        const userProfileImg = await snap.data().userProfileImg;
        const date = await snap.data().date;

        // Notification details.
        const payload = {
            notification: {
                title: `Test SocialWifi de: ${user}`,
                body: `Hoy: ${date} , Nuevo Mensaje  ${message}`,
                icons: `${userProfileImg}`,
                click_action: 'https://sudokudetodos.com'
            }
        };

        console.info(payload);

    });
```

> Si no funciona `snap.data()` podes probar con `snap.val()`

Comment: Muchas Gracias Gaston Saillen..funciono muy bien ...

Answer (score 1):

El codigo que me funciono tal como me lo recomendo Gaston Saillen es el siguiente :

```
'use strict';
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


    exports.Notifications = functions.database.ref('/notifications/{notificationId}')
        .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
            const user = await snap.val().user;
            const message = await snap.val().message;
            const userProfileImg = await snap.val().userProfileImg;
            const date = await snap.val().date;

            // Notification details.
            const payload = {
                notification: {
                    title: `Test SocialWifi de: ${user}`,
                    body: `Hoy: ${date} , Nuevo Mensaje  ${message}`,
                    icons: `${userProfileImg}`,
                    click_action: 'https://sudokudetodos.com'
                }
            };

            console.info(payload);

        });
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]